# Ветошный переулок - ударение

Tags: топонимика

Ветошный переулок. Почему Вет**о**шный, ветошь ударяют же на первой гласной?

Comment: Метку, ранее - "название", теперь - "топонимика" (не моя работа), если и хочется поменять, то на "значение слов". Вопрос не о переулке, хотя замечательно, что имя ему вернули.

Comment: Напишите тогда, о чем вопрос тогда. Не об ударении же в прилагательном? Это отдельная тема - и неблагодарная. Таких тысячи примеров, что делать, если в русском языке ударение подвижное.

Comment: Напишите в таком случае, о чем вопрос. Не об ударении же в прилагательном? Это отдельная тема - и неблагодарная. Таких тысячи примеров, что делать, если в русском языке ударение подвижное. –

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Ветошный переулок. Почему Ветошный, **ветошь ударяют же на первой
> гласной**?

А ***ветошье*** (то же, что ***ветошь***) и ***ветошка*** -- на второй.
Из "Словаря церковно-славянского и русского языка" середины 19-го века:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

========================

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

========================

Почему в слове ***ветошный*** ударение на втором слоге? Наверное, потому, что и в словах ***ветошка, ветошье, ветошник, ветошница, ветошничать*** оно на втором слоге.

Ну а объяснить, почему в слове ***ветошь*** ударение на первом слоге, а не на втором, как у всех других однокоренных с ***ветошью*** словах, я не смогу.
Так же, как не смогу объяснить, к примеру, почему в слове ***подпушь*** оно на первом слоге, в словах ***подпушек*** и ***подпушка*** -- на втором, а в слове ***подпушённый*** -- на третьем… Наверное, просто так на сегодняшний день сложилось. Что будет в будущем… -- ?

Comment: На картинке нет слова "ветошье". А если бы и было, на вопрос "почему" не отвечает. )))

Comment: Продолжу: "Не на втором, как у всех других однокоренных с ветошью"  есть ещё "ветхий". Спасибо за справку от XIX в.

Comment: "Ветошье (то же, что ветошь)"? Среднего рода да и пошире значение имеет.

Answer (score 0):

Потому, что так в русском языке. 
Ударение в прилагательном - нормативно на втором слоге: вет**о**шный.
http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%E2%E5%F2%EE%F8%ED%FB%E9&all=x

Вопрос "почему" был бы в какой-то мне уместен, отличайся оно в имени собственном (топониме) от обычного прилагательного - хотя и такое бывает без всяких видимых причин. Но когда топоним следует общим нормам, тут и обсуждать нечего.

Исторически здесь был **ветошный ряд**, шде продавалась ветошка. Но это уже другой вопрос. Само по себе ничего не добавляет к правильному ударению. 
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA